# Multiple electrical issues or what?

Tags: electrical, kia, sorento

Hi there I have a 2005 Kia Sorento LX 3.5L. First the power windows do not work and no power to the 2 25amp fuses. Next I found a little problem. I had to change the fuse block due to a broken connection for a terminal block. Putting the negative battery cable back on little arch when cable touched battery. Started pulling fuses at engine bay fuse block till test light went out. 
The fuse for the audio when pulled light went dim. Then the relay for the defroster started clicking rapidly, pulled it light went out.
Now with battery cable off the fuse block still shows 12.86 volts when dvom lead is put to negative terminal and other to fuse block.
Key is out radio out, defroster switch out, doors closed with nothing on still shows power with cable off the battery.
Help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Changing a fuse block is a LOT of wires.  Are you sure you got them all rght?

Comment: I got everything working as it is supposed to work then another failure. Key in to "start" position and lights are but nobody home. The damn fuse panel at the drivers kick panel just clicks. I am really starting to hate this thing.